# Traefik get destination router/container in ForwardAuth middleware

Tags: docker, authentication, traefik

We are currently building a [ForwardAuth](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/) middleware for [Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik).

[image: diagram]

We want to add user groups and give different groups access to different routers (/containers). How can we get info about D in FA to verify that the user has the permission to access D? For example, the container ID of D would be very useful to have in FA, but it doesn't seem like this is possible. We would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

For the way I used and implemented FA before, I never needed information about D (and I thought that was the whole beauty of it).

There are rules defined in FA that would allow a user through or not. Those can come from anywhere needed (internal logic, database, other external systems - just not D in your case). Once the user is allowed through, I attach relevant headers to the request and that is what is forwarded to Traefik to serve. In your example, the user role could become one of the headers.

Now the routes defined in Traefik each accept requests, if certain hearders with certain values are present. And that is done with labels (in docker).

So the FA and D remain decoupled as they should be.

Would this approach work for your case as well?

Comment: Routers are determined before middlewares are run, how can you add a header rule, if it gets set by the middleware? The router (should) not even execute the middleware, if the header rule does not match. Could you post an example, maybe?

Comment: You are right, my answer is wrong. I will delete it eventually. However I think what you need is the service name, not the container ID. And the service name you should already have.